# Do I need a host app for an iOS 10 Messages extension?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval, ios10

I am building a messages extension for iOS 10 and I am wondering if I am required to make a host app or can I just publish my messages extension directly on the app store?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple:

> You can use the Messages framework to create two types of app extensions: Sticker packs and iMessage apps. Both extension types can be created as standalone apps or as app extensions within a containing iOS app.

With that, you should be able to publish your extension directly on the app store.

Comment: good to hear thanks for the reply

Comment: @user1851782 You're welcome!